# Populating Value and Text of ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, combobox

I have a `combobox` called `ddCourses` on my form.  I'm trying to load it with a LINQ expression, but when I run the program, the `combobox` is showing the value (COURSE_ID) and text (COURSE_TITLE) that I loaded with the LINQ statement, instead of just the text (I want the Value, COURSE_ID, hidden).

Here's my code:

```
    private void LoadDropDowns()
    {
        var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        ddCourse.DataSource = (from c in db.COURSE_MASTERs
                               select new { c.COURSE_ID, c.COURSE_TITLE }).ToList();
    }
```

How can I set the Value and Text of each row of the `combobox`?

Other examples I've seen have used `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties, but these do not seem to be available to me.

Am I missing a reference in my `using` statements that would allow me to have access to the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties?

Here's my 'using' statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

EDIT:  The DataTextField and DataValueField properties are not available to me.  Is this because they are part of System.Web.UI and this is a winform I'm using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` first:

```
var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
ddCourse.DisplayMember = "COURSE_TITLE";
ddCourse.ValueMember = "COURSE_ID";
ddCourse.DataSource = (from c in db.COURSE_MASTERs
                        select new { c.COURSE_ID, c.COURSE_TITLE }).ToList();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks so much!  As soon as timer is up, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Display and value member are needed.

```
ddCourse.DataSource = (from c in db.COURSE_MASTERs 
                       select new {course_id = c.COURSE_ID, course_title = c.COURSE_TITLE }).ToList();
comboBox.DisplayMember="course_title";
comboBox.ValueMember="course_id ";
```

Comment: Should be case sensitive. remember this is c#

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare 2 more propriety :

```
cmbbox.ValueMember // value selected

cmbbox.DisplayMember // value display
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning anonymous type, you can return a class from query that includes properties you want. Then override ToString() method of this class and return desired property with ToString() method. ToString() method result will be shown on Combobox.

Here sample code block worked for me.

```
    public class ComboItem
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Text;
            }
        }

  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<ComboItem> itemList = new List<ComboItem>()
            {
                new ComboItem() { Text="A", Value="1"},
                new ComboItem() { Text="B", Value="2"},
                new ComboItem() { Text="C", Value="3"},
                new ComboItem() { Text="D", Value="4"},
                new ComboItem() { Text="E", Value="5"}
            };

            comboBox1.DataSource = itemList;
        }
```

And you can get selectedItem's value with below code:

```
 string selectedVal = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboItem).Value;
```