# Populate a dropbox that contains the names and Project ID

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

i have to create a project managing system using C#.

My question is how do I populate my dropdown with the project names and keep the project ID hidden. So when I add a task I can choose the project to add a task too.

The information I want to have inside the combobox (e.g. this will be coming from the database):

```
Project 1    
Project 2    
Project 3
```

What I want to be hidden:

```
ProjectID = 1
ProjectID = 2
ProjectID = 3
```

So when I select the project, I will also have the ID to use in my query.

This is how my form looks like now:

[image: C# form]

Comment: What platform is this? WPF?

Comment: @itsme86 If you mean what software im using, its Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Commonly when you are getting data from database you saved it in a DataTable or a generic datasource. So when you are binding your combobox, you should do something like this:

```
 DataTable data = data_from_database(); //method that returns your data
 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "title";
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
 comboBox1.DataSource = data;
```

Get it from [Populating value and text of ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880534/populating-value-and-text-of-combobox)

Comment: Do i do this inside the load? or where do i put this in?

Comment: Yes, you should put it inside the load_page. When you are adding that code you are telling your combobox to use the datatable as its source of data and that it has to show the 'title' column and saved the 'id' column related.

Comment: So what do i fill in at data_from_database();? Do i make a query for it?

Comment: What do you do inside of data_from_database() is returning a Datatable with your data, it could be filled either from a store procedure or from a string execution directly connected to you database.

Comment: String execution directly connect to your database? How would i do that. Sorry i have been trying stuff and googling stuff for 2 days now, cant find anything that doesnt use a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Combobox

```
  Droplist.DataSource = GetListItems(); //Get  data from database.
  Droplist.DataValueField = "Value";
  Droplist.DataTextField = "DisplayText";
  Droplist.DataBind();
```

Comment: And how do i make it so i can fill the GetListItems(); With values? I had this awnser before but i dont know how to make it work in my form.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void LoadSubjects()
    {
        List<ProjectItem> items = new List<ProjectItem>();

        string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                con.Open();
                string query = "SELECT ID, Naam FROM projecten";

                MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

                MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int id = (int)reader["ID"];
                    string nm = (string)reader["Naam"];
                    items.Add(new ProjectItem(id, nm));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ex));
        }
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray<ProjectItem>());  
    }
```